# Handling push notification payload data

Tags: swift

how to handle push notification when app is in foreground and background. I'm getting the below payload data.

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

```
    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    print(userInfo)
```

// [title: push, body: hi, collapse_key: do_not_collapse, icon: icon, from: 27]

}

how to handle this payload to get notification?

Comment: I am also similar kind of payload but not getting notification in foreground or background . How did u handle this kind of payload

Comment: you can use BRYXBanner to show notification when app is in running state.

Comment: when app is in background or foreground means

Comment: banner is shown when app is in foreground. the format of payload must be as per apple to show notification in background

Comment: Thank You. May I know the format of payload for apple and who should provide this kind of payload . Please let me know this thing .

Comment: payload should be provided by server side. refer this link for payload. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146223/discussion-between-uma-madhavi-and-thripthi-haridas).

Answer (score 0):

You already received the notification. This is up to you what action you want to perform. You can parse the payload and process the data accordingly.

If you are asking to handle the notification in App's "not running" state. Then iOS handles itself handles the notification to process and show but the format should be as per defined by apple.